# Compiler errors in FlashDevelop which don't appear in Flash Builder?

Tags: compiler-construction, flash-builder, flashdevelop

I'm trying to build a project with FlashDevelop, which I was able to build using Flash Builder without any special settings.

FlashDevelop shows errors:

"Ambiguous reference to..."

"A conflict exists with inherited definition..."

and doesn't compile.

I looked in compile settings but didn't find a way to disable this.

Don't advice me to fix the errors, I just want to know why it works in Flash Builder and not in FlashDevelop.

Comment: You need to provide the complete error messages. This isn't an error you can just ignore but a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a different Flex SDK (removed version name from the directory, and assumed it was the same...).